# Slide jumping from left to right at the edge of the browser

Tags: jquery, css

HTML

```
<div class="sidebar-panel">
  <div>
    <div style="border: 1px solid #eee;">
      test
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JQuery

```
 $('.icon-btn').on('click', function() {
        var offset = $(window).width() - 440;
        $('#overlay').addClass('overlay');
        $('.sidebar-panel').animate({
            'left': offset
        });

    });
    $('#overlay').click(function() {
        var offset = $(window).width() + 440;
        $(this).removeClass('overlay').delay(10000);
        $('.sidebar-panel').animate({
            'left': offset
        });
    });
```

CSS

```
.overlay{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 9000;
  background-color: #000;
}

.sidebar-panel{
  width: 440px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: calc(100% + 640px);
  background: #f9f9f9;
  padding: 35px;
  z-index: 9100;
  overflow-y: auto;

}
```

When click on icon button, it would display overlay and slide from right at the edge of the browser. The problem is that my calculation for left may not be right. On testing browser, upon click icon btn, the slide-panel slide from left to right. then after one time, tried again, it slide correctly from right to 0 at right.

Also is there a way for overlay and slide panel to close together at the same time?

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sNv2X/)
It seems to be working, but it only have problem with safari.

Wanted to change calculation to allow that slide correctly on all browsers.

**Updated**

```
    .sidebar-panel{
    width: 440px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right:-100%;
    background: #f9f9f9;
    padding: 35px;
    z-index: 9100;
    overflow-y: auto;
 -webkit-transition: all 1000ms cubic-bezier(0.190, 1.000, 0.220, 1.000);
     -moz-transition: all 1000ms cubic-bezier(0.190, 1.000, 0.220, 1.000);
       -o-transition: all 1000ms cubic-bezier(0.190, 1.000, 0.220, 1.000);
          transition: all 1000ms cubic-bezier(0.190, 1.000, 0.220, 1.000); /* easeOutExpo */
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.190, 1.000, 0.220, 1.000);
     -moz-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.190, 1.000, 0.220, 1.000);
       -o-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.190, 1.000, 0.220, 1.000);
          transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.190, 1.000, 0.220, 1.000); /* easeOutExpo */
}
```

When close the sidebar panel, it slide out too fast. Is there any way to make slide in and out in same transition way?

Comment: Can you include a fiddle?

Comment: I"m confused by what exactly you are trying to do. I'm running FF, and when I click, the overlay appears, full width, covering everything. Then it and the sidebar both slide left-wards 440px. What is different about what you want.

Comment: @AndyM - it does work as expected, but if you check Safari (just tested again to confirm), it will slide from left to right which is wrong.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sNv2X/1/ why use calc and left, when you can use `right:0;` and `right:-100%;`?

Comment: @haxxxton - oh nice, but it is still having a bit issue on safari - not much slide

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sNv2X/3/ Tested on Safari on Windows. It's rather laggy, but it works.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sNv2X/4/ - If you change it over to use CSS animations, it animates more smoothly. Add a css `transition` style, then just use jQuery's `.css()` instead of `.animate()`.

Comment: @AndyM - you are right and use css animation, but when click btn the slide is too fast then click overlay slide slow.

Comment: The speed of sliding is the same, because clicking only changes the position. The speed of the sliding is controlled by the CSS rule.

Comment: @joe if you position the overlay PRIOR to applying the class using CSS, and use the class just to change z-index and background color it works nicely in Safari: see here: http://jsfiddle.net/sNv2X/6/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a `class` based solution, that i find to work much nicer cross browser (NOTE: this uses CSS3 transitions rather than javascript animations)

**CSS**

```
#overlay{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #000;
    z-index:-1;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility:hidden;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear;
       -moz-transition: all 0.2s linear;
        -ms-transition: all 0.2s linear;
         -o-transition: all 0.2s linear;
            transition: all 0.2s linear;
}
.sidePanelOpen #overlay{
    opacity:1;
    visibility:visible;
    z-index: 9000;
}

.sidebar-panel{
    width: 440px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right:-100%;
    background: #f9f9f9;
    padding: 35px;
    z-index: 9100;
    overflow-y: auto;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear;
       -moz-transition: all 0.2s linear;
        -ms-transition: all 0.2s linear;
         -o-transition: all 0.2s linear;
            transition: all 0.2s linear;
}
.sidePanelOpen .sidebar-panel{
    right:0;
}
```

**JS**

```
$('.icon-btn').on('click', function() {
    $('body').addClass('sidePanelOpen');

});
$('#overlay').on('click', function() {
    $('body').removeClass('sidePanelOpen');
});
```

All you're doing is adding and removing a body class that then transitions the panel

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sNv2X/5/)

PS. Im pretty sure the issue was that you were applying the positioning to the overlay along with the class, rather than positioning the element and just toggling it's visibility. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/sNv2X/6/

Comment: @haxxton - wow thanks. but it is still too fast to slide forward and back. is it due to 0.2s?

Comment: @joe yeah you can adjust those values to your hearts content, you can even adjust the in vs out timing by applying a different transition speed to the .sidePanelOpen version. For a basic solution to what you originally ran with, have a look at my 'PS' answer

Comment: yeah understood. so using body is easy to apply / remove class. thanks alot. next question is if i want to have close button outside the sidebar panel, it would be positioned absolute correct?

Comment: depends where in the DOM the close button is. i would assume that yes it would be positioned absolutely, and probably inside the sidepanel div. i cant really advise without seeing a design or example of what you're thinking of :) Also if you find an answer to work for you dont forget to mark it as the solution for the sake of other people looking for a solution :)

Comment: thanks so much. close button will be outside the sidebar panel at top 0. i will do it first before asking for help :D. yup going to mark it

Comment: sorry to bother you, but see [link](http://jsfiddle.net/sNv2X/7/) - red box is under the overlay and not sure why it is behaving like that. position abs seem not to be working so i replace with relative

Comment: @joe you have overflow-x: and overflow-y: on the sidepanel that are causing the close button to be partially hidden. I would also recommend using absolute for the position of your close button in this case. have a look here http://jsfiddle.net/sNv2X/8/

Comment: thanks so much but it does not work so I decide to make another div to contain all content instead. One more issue i realize is that when slide in, it is slow but when close sidepanel, it slide out too fast. is there any way to make them slide in and out in same transition?